# will_paginate gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm having a problem with `will_paginate` that's pretty simple to express:

```
> Story.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 10).count
=> 20
```

Obviously, that number should be 10, not 20.

Am I somehow doing something wrong? Doesn't seem like there's much room for error here, but obviously something isn't right. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the `SQL` query that was run in the background?

Comment: There is a reported bug in `will_paginate` at https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/449 but it doesn't seem to be addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `Story.paginate(page: 1, per_page:10).size`, not `count`. Count will actually return the total numbers of records generated by your query.

Answer (score 0):

Because `will_paginate` gem overrides the `count` method

```
def count(*args)
  if limit_value
    excluded = [:order, :limit, :offset, :reorder]
    excluded << :includes unless eager_loading?
    rel = self.except(*excluded)
    column_name = (select_for_count(rel) || :all)
    rel.count(column_name)
  else
    super(*args)
  end
end
```

It will exculde `order, limit, offset and reorder`. [link to code](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/bad024662f78983a609e4e5ddd886e35a962a51c/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb#L81)

You should use `size` or `total_entries`